# how to fix variables starting with tags in php

Tags: php, html, variables, tags

I have the following code:

```
$name = "<test>";

$msg = "Hi $name Hope your feeling well today";

print_r ($msg);
```

The problem is, it will print `Hi Hope your feeling well today` and skip the `$name`

When I tried it this way:

```
$name = "<test>";

$msg = "Hi ".$name." Hope your feeling well today";

print_r ($msg);
```

it also printed the same.

When I tried it as:

```
$name = "<test>";

$msg = 'Hi $name Hope your feeling well today';

print_r ($msg);
```

it printed `Hi $name Hope your feeling well today`

I need a solution so that the variable `$name` will be printed as it is if starting with `<` or any other PHP related code.

Answer (score 3):

View the source of your web page. It is there. You don't see it because it is in brackets which the browser interprets as HTML. Since HTML tags are interpreted and not displayed, you don't see that content.

To display those brackets, you need to convert them into HTML entities. You can use the aptly named [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) function to do that.

```
$name = "<test>";
$msg = "Hi $name Hope your feeling well today";
echo htmlentities($msg, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: lol I was just going to say that, in comments; *just in case* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I would have expected nothing less from you! Merry Christmas (20 minutes early)!

Comment: Thanks, and Merry Christmas to you too John, *cheers* (as per our other place of chatting, sent earlier) ;-)

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution it did work for < but didnt work for $ sign in name
this is what i did
`$name = "$test";

 $name = htmlentities($name, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');

 $mess = "Hi $name Hope your feeling well today";

print_r ($mess);`
and i just got blank for the $name

Comment: *Oh,* the plot thickens, as it were.

Comment: @Fred-ii-,
the name variable can be anything the user chooses as `$test` or `"me"`
so i need a way that the value of `$name` would not effect the code
thanks again and Merry Christmas

Comment: That's because PHP sees the `$` as meaning `$test` is a variable. You either need to escape the `$` or [use single quotes](http://codepad.viper-7.com/TjPri6).

Comment: @guestofhonor77 Thanks and Merry Christmas to you also, *cheers*

Comment: @JohnConde, 
i guess my question wasn't 100% clear and i'm sorry for that
here's the main idea of the code
`preg_match('%<b class="(.*)">(.*)</b>%U', $mess, $match);

$name = $match[2];
$name = htmlentities($name, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');`
please note that `$mess` is acquired using `file_get_contents` and then `explode`

Comment: The code I posted should still work as it doesn't matter where that value came from

Answer (score 0):

Write instead of < `&lt;` and instead of > `&gt;`

Comment: it's a user name variable that i cannot control, i used str_replace which worked but it's not a solid solution
regards

Comment: For this problem I think str_replace is a good solution and there is no standard solution.

Comment: but i don't want to strip_tags :)
i know there is a solution for this but i just can't find it
anyway thanks a lot for your help